# How to configure ContextLoaderListener to not look for applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, jersey, grizzly

I'm trying to steer clear of XML based configuration within my application and would like to maintain all configuration within the code.  Currently the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` looks for `applicationContext.xml`.

Is it possible for me to turn that off so it doesn't require that file?

Currently main() looks like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    //enable web socket support
    final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();
    for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
        listener.registerAddOn(addon);

        //if false, local files (html, etc.) can be modified without restarting the server
        //@todo experiment with this setting in production vs development
        listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
    }

    //add jersey servlet support
    /*ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer());
    jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "come.fettergroup.production.queue.resources");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");*/

    //add atmosphere servlet support
    AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
    AtmosphereFramework f = atmosphereServlet.framework();

    ReflectorServletProcessor r = new ReflectorServletProcessor();
    r.setServletClassName("com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet");

    f.addAtmosphereHandler("/socket/*", r);

    ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", atmosphereServlet);
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType", "application/json");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    ctx.deploy(server);

    //serve static assets
    StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/web");
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");

    //start the production process
    Production.init();

    server.start();

    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
}
```

Comment: Where does `WebappContext` come from?

Comment: I'm guessing it's pretty telling that I don't know...

Comment: Can you look at the package name?

Comment: org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this yet but the org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener class needs to be configured to use an annotation scanning application context.  This is done via context parameters.

So in a web.xml file, you would do something like this:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yourbasepackage</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

For a standalone Jetty, you need to do something similar using the [WebAppContext.setInitParameter()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setInitParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

```
ctx.setInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
ctx.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.yourbasepackage");
```

Comment: Using Grizzly, small fix:
`ctx.addContextInitParameter(name, value)`